# Spring-Boot, mySQL, using select

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am working on a project where an item has multiple sizes and will have a selector for the user to select the desired size.  Since the item has multiple sections do I set up my java class as follows

```
private String option1;
private String option2;
private String option3;
etc...
//Generated getters and setters
```

so that they are placed into the database for that particular item when i add the item via the admin portal and called to the needed page using thymeleaf? or is there another way I need to go about adding those fields to the database for that particular item?  Every example i've found so far has the options hard coded into the java class.  That does me no good when the options are not static, and item dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two tables for example:

```
item(id, name);
item_size(id, item_id, size);
```

So your Java class would be something like:

```
public class Item {
    String id; 
    String name;
    List<ItemSize> sizes;
}

public class ItemSize {
    String id;
    String itemId;
    String size;
}
```

So from the admin you keep adding entries to `item_size` table and then in the client populate the `select` from the `item` and `item_size` table by doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN something like:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, itemS.size 
FROM item 
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_size itemS ON itemS.item_id = item.id;
```